# Is there a diff algorithm that accounts for repositions?

Tags: java, algorithm, diff

I was checking the Myers algorithm but in cases like:

```
"A", "B", "C", "D", "0", "E", "F", "I"        - original
                     ^
"A", "B", "Z", "X", "E", "F", "G", "H", "0"   - revised
                                         ^
```

Where the 0 moved from 4th to 8th index, the algorithm only gives a "change" from length to length.

I do have an algorithm created by me that s able to check for repositions, but because it uses 2 HashMaps and is unable to check for lengths at a time --(only index by index that - even if the check is performed only once it's still too much)-- it is too slow,

The component gives callbacks for what I call "explicit" removes with their corresponding index, it also gives callbacks for "removes by repostion" with an int oldIndex, ... it gives reposition (int fromIndex, int toIndex) and insertion (int at)...

I'm just wondering what algorithm is able to give me this kind of detailed information.

I am aware I can build upon the Myers algorithm and give it an extra layer for more detailed information, but I think I could make it as slow as what I've got, specially since I need to check for equalities on any delta type "change" and subList()-ing would create new Lists on each hypothetical transaction... also what .contains() ?? smh...

I have seen the android libraries have a method from its diffUtil callBack (which uses the same Myers algorithm) called `onMoved(int fromPosition, int toPosition)`, but I have seen this does not actually tells me when something moved... so I dont know why that's there...

Comment: This sounds related to [sequence alignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_alignment)

Comment: Thanks for your answer @xdhmoore . The paragraph that said -- "These include slow but formally correct methods" -- did not gave me much hope lol, If that's the case I think the only thing missing from my algorithm, would be to integrate an optimized form of concurrency....

Comment: The two I'm at all familiar with use dynamic programming, differing in whether they compare the whole sequence or a subsequence ([global alignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Needleman%E2%80%93Wunsch_algorithm) vs [local alignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Waterman_algorithm)). But you'd probably need to modify them to give you the info you need. And idk, there maybe newer, faster ways. It also depends on how long your sequences are, though these are used to compare strings of DNA, which can be pretty long...

Comment: Rhetorically, how do you know that the zero in "revised" is the same zero as in "original" and not an entirely new zero that was added (and the one in "original" deleted)?

Comment: @500 My component makes use of 2 boolean checks, one where a condition of id equality must be met:(Function<X, Long>) idFunc.apply(newItem) == idFun.apply(oldItem) Tells me whether there has been an ID match, a second where a specified content is also checked (conentFun.apply(newItem) == contentFun.apply(oldItem)).

This will tell whether the 0 is the same or not.

I could implement and add it to the Myers algo, but I believe I need to use memory no matter what

What I suspect the android and other platforms are doing are resolving equalities AFTER the algorithm has ended, making it slow

Comment: *.. even slower than if the equality check would be properly integrated in the diagonals path build.

Ofc this is just a speculation, but I believe in the case of android, is that the replaced items id's are checked against a pool of cached views. and this is how it figures out whether the items replaced are the same and moved.

The problem is that the animations are unable to move the 0 from that point to the end, all it does is push chunks and insert, or remove chuncks and pull the immediate items, but the binded information for the 0 is binded properly nontheless.

Comment: But my own counter question to yours would be how does the Myers algorithm knows that the "A" in the original is the same as the one in the revised ?.

Comment: @Delark: It doesn't, of course - how could it? That was my point, actually: In your example above, a value is deleted ('0') and anothers inserted ('G', 'H', '0') one of the inserts happens to be identical to the delete, but isn't that just coincidence?

Comment: It seems to me you need some sort of sync threshold value so that only sequences longer than this values are to be considered the same sequence, relocated (as opposed to deletes followed by inserts, or vice versa).

Comment: @500 Maybe the problem is that I am not thinking in terms of "sequences", but I am thinking of the individual state of indices.
Imagine a game in which a set of characters with their own hp are rearranged on any arbitrary order, without a known path, and you want to keep their stats intact.
If one of the characters receives such an arbitrary diff position from the original, the Myers algorithm will lose its state.

Comment: As of now I have defined a specific set of rules before submitting lists to the component mentioned before, because If I don't the exact problem you are talking of arises.
This rules requires for each entity to have its own unique id, and an specified content.
This algorithm I created is absolutely nothing special, it's simply how a 5 yo would rearrange a List to another list. Which implies....a non deterministic loop inside a deterministic one...lol... I'm not proud of it, but I am stubborn and I thought I could do it...
As of now it's working but I would not use it on anything lengthy.